# BIOS - Change order of hard disk device to boot

Tags: boot, bios, grub

I did an installtion of a Linux distro onto a USB and it all went fine. I've been using the BIOS settings to choose whether I want to boot the hard disk (with just Windows) and the USB.

All seems to be working fine. However, whenever the computer boots now, it only displays `grub>`.

After I restarted and opened BIOS, when I select my hard disk, it now gives me a further prompt:

```
ubuntu
Windows Boot Manager
Ubuntu
```

What I would like to do, is to have Windows be the default boot device *unless* I accesses the BIOS settings, or have the USB in. In BIOS mode, I can change the order of the hardware I want to boot from, but I can't see a way to configure Windows Boot Manager to be the default.

Is there a way to do this through the BIOS config? Or do I need to configure grub as it seems to have inserted 2 new entries?

**EDIT:**

The plot thickens. I get a normal grub menu when my USB is inserted, and can thereby boot windows, or the linux distribution. However, it's only when my USB is plugged in. I still only get the `grub>` prompt when the USB is not inserted.

How can I:

Have grub provide me with the same menu on hard disk boot?

or

Reset my drive's settings to that I can boot Windows automatically (unless the USB is inserted)?

Comment: It looks like you installed GRUB on your Windows system disk instead of the USB drive.  You should see those options only when the USB drive is plugged in and it has boot priority.  When that's not the case, your system shouldn't be aware of anything but Windows.

Comment: Darn, I was afraid of that. I definitely installed the OS on the USB but the installer must have put it on there. I take it I need to configure grub then?

Comment: You can certainly leave GRUB on your Windows drive and use it, just clean it up if you don't like the redundant entry.  I'm not familiar with how to undo the GRUB installation and return it to the original Windows boot loader.  You might be able to clean it up just running the [GRUB boot repair tool](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair).

Comment: Thanks again. I booted to my Linux distro and made a couple changes in grub config to set default to the index of the windows partition, and shortened the time to 2 seconds, and ran grub update. I now have windows boot after a 2 second delay. Thanks!

Comment: Glad you got it working.  Consider writing up an answer with how you fixed it.  That could be useful to others with a similar problem.

Comment: Hm, scratch that. It only seems to work the way I expect when the USB is plugged in. I suspect I need to edit BIOS settings for the internal as it's trying to boot the first in the list, and is failing when it can't find the OS.

Comment: Have you tried the GRUB Boot Repair Tool mentioned in the earlier comment?

Comment: I'm not really willing to disable secureboot in the bios settings in order to run the tool. I've already had enough "tools" affecting low level settings, and I don't want to compromise anything else without running commands myself.